# JSON schema - reference dynamic property names in array

Tags: jsonschema

I would like to validate (and autocomplete) values in an array against properties of an object.

Consider this data example:

```json
{
   "scripts": {
      "prepare": { "command": "./prepare.sh" },
      "buildSrc": { "command": "./build-src.sh" },
      "buildDocs": { "command": "./build-docs.sh" },
      "publish": { "command": "./publish.sh" }
   },
   "pipelines": {
      "buildProd": ["prepare", "buildSrc", "buildDocs", "publish"],
      "buildDev": ["prepare", "buildSrc"]
   }
}
```

The properties of the `scripts` object can be named whatever you want and I need the values of the arrays of the properties in `pipelines` to match against the properties of `scripts`. I.e. it should show an error if you reference a script which hasn't been defined. (And preferably get editors to suggest existing names from the `scripts` object.)

Is this something that's possible to define in JSON Schemas?